# How to generate a file with BOM for multiple schematics - EAGLE

Tags: components, eaglecad

I've 3 boards each with it's own schematic but with a lot of common components. I want to generate an unique BOM for all this boards to know quantity of each piece I need and make a single order BOM.

For example:
I can extract a single BOM with
run bom.ulp

But now I want to merge this BOMs in a single file with quantities of a common single piece sum togheder.

There is a method in EAGLE or Excel to do this? I want avoid to manually do this becouse of risk to make errors in count or add pieces.

Comment: What about copying the content of each board to a new empty board and generating the BOM for it? The schematics have to be closed. And, it's not very comfortable, but works.

Comment: Have done with this method.

Answer (score 2):

```
File > Import > Eagle drawing > select the schematics that you want to import
```

Each schematic will be a new page (you should see them on the left menu numbered as 1,2,3) then click on

```
File > Export > BOM
```

Then select values and CSV file type (shown below). [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is an universal file format that you can open with Excell or Open Office (or a text editor).

[image]

If you use Excell, then you can use `=SUM()` command to get the number of components.